# c# .net core linq to entities async call terminates program

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, .net-core

In .Net core I have a query and would like to get the result async but the program simply terminates without any error.

Code is something like this:

```
var query = from row in context.MyTable 
            where something == row.something 
            select row;
var list = await query.ToListAsync();
```

The program also terminates if I do a FirstAsync, but it runs fine if I do a First() or ToList().

I have many other queries that behaves fine, and I am thinking a termination is fairly brutal, but I cannot find any other that have experienced it.

What can I try to resolve it? (For now I just use ToList)

Comment: no exception? whether turned on the exception settings?

Comment: How do I turn that on? The program just dissapear if I run it from a console, unit test returns success because it terminates without reaching my asserts and when called from a webservice the service just exits.

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)

Comment: Just checked all the top level, I think that enables all exceptions. Program still just dissapear. But then I learned something new

Comment: subscribe to UnhandledException  and UnobservedTaskException https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/

Comment: I could not find UnobservedTaskException, but UnhandledException was enabled becuase I have enabled everything by checking toplevel of all noted in the Exception Settings window.

Comment: There is high chance that your console program just exists because it reaches end of Main method. If you put what you describe in `async Task` method and then run that method from Main of your console app without waiting for it to complete - that is what will happen.

Comment: All my methods return Task<Something>. Then what you write isn't an issue right? I dont have any Task (void Task).

Comment: Ok, that explains why it doesn't work in my console app. It still doesn't explain why my service fails. But the solution to half of it was to make my integration test a Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Main function is always synchronous your top level Task should be waited synchronously:

```
void Main()
{
    var serviceTask = StartServiceAsync();

    // you cannot do await serviceTask, but only
    serviceTask.Wait();
}
```

So your service probably doesn't fail - it's just terminated as Main func reached the end and app is closed.